# Were Jesus' last words grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Consider this last phrase of Jesus, [as found on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayings_of_Jesus_on_the_cross#1._Father,_forgive_them,_for_they_know_not_what_they_do):

> Father, forgive them, for they know not what they do

I have a problem with the phrase: "...*know not*...". I am not a native speaker and find this phrase confusing. To me, it suggests the same idea as this complete phrase: "they know, not what they do, *rather they know something else* (which they do not do)". I honestly wonder if this is in fact the true interpretation.

> I wish to know if this phrase structure is correct English grammar.

Thank you!

Comment: In case of any clarification, please comment. Thank you!

Comment: They were grammatical for the time in which that English was written. Also, Jesus did not speak English. Those words are a translation of an ancient text, which was itself a translation.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Oh! I did not know that before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know not = You don't know.

In normal formal or informal English, you use the phrases do not, does not, and did not in front of a verb like know to form the negative.  The structure verb + not is highly formal, especially found in scriptures, poetry,old English, etc. Moreover, this structure makes a stronger statement.